# Facebook app fails to get Session

Tags: php, facebook, heroku, facebook-php-sdk

I'm developing a very basic PHP app on Heroku for Facebook which shows very basic user info like Name, Profile Picture, but the app halts in getToken method !
I've tried the app after logging in my profile still the same message :

Here are the codes

**composer.json**

```
{}
```

**index.php**

```
    session_start();
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );
    require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

    use Facebook\FacebookSession;
    use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
    use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
    use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
    use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
    use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
    use Facebook\GraphObject;
    use Facebook\GraphUser;
    use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication($id, $secret);
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://facebook.com');

try{
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(Exception $e){  echo 'Error in Session > '.$e;
}

if(isset($_SESSION['token'])){
    $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['token']);
    try{
        $session->Validate($id, $secret);
    }catch(FacebookAuthorizationException $e){
    echo 'Error in Token >'.$e;     $session = '';
    }
}

if(isset($session)){
    $_SESSION['token'] = $session->getToken();
    echo "Login Successful<br>";
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
    echo "Hi " . $graph->getName();
}
else{
    echo "<a href = " . $helper->getLoginUrl() . ">Login With Facebook</a>";
}
```

The app always goes to the **Login With Facebook** ,the last else part !
Where the problem lies ?
I'm completely new to this Heroku and Facebook SDK v4 and after searching for hours did not found any sample app on Facebook for Heroku ~

Comment: I've Windows 7, git installed
 Heroku uses PHP 5.5.4

Comment: What happens when you click on Login?

Comment: The app frame gets blank !

Comment: You must be getting some error. Can you share the link if its live?

Comment: Sorry, it's not live and as per Fb guideline it takes 7 to 14 business days to get approval for an app. :/

Comment: Only if you are submitting something for reviews, else it becomes live at that time only. btw, you must show some error etc to get it solved. How can one even guess what's happening here?

Comment: https://apps.facebook.com/soutestapp

Comment: Go the settings. Status&Review and make your app live. I cant access your app

Comment: it's live, please check

Comment: Why the login helper is redirected here 'http://facebook.com' ??

Comment: changing that had no effect

Comment: either $_SESSION['token'] or $session is wrong just before your if else

try adding a var_dump of those two bastards lets see if that clears up

Answer (score -1):

Try changing your code to this and see if it helps:

```
if ( isset( $_SESSION['token'] ) ) {
    $session = new FacebookSession($_SESSION['token']);
    try{
        $session->Validate($id, $secret);
    }catch(FacebookAuthorizationException $e){
    echo 'Error in Token >'.$e;     $session = '';
        $session = null;
    }
} else {
    $session = null;
}

// if session is null, try getting it from redirect
if ( $session === null ) {
    try{
        $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
    } catch(Exception $e){  echo 'Error in Session > '.$e;
    }
}

if ( isset( $session ) && $session != null ) {
    $_SESSION['token'] = $session->getToken();
    echo "Login Successful<br>";
    $request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/me');
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graph = $response->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());
    echo "Hi " . $graph->getName();
}
else{
    echo "<a href = " . $helper->getLoginUrl() . ">Login With Facebook</a>";
}
```

I've uses a similar method to the [code shown here](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/).

Comment: after clicking LOGIN blank frame comes