# Support end time of FB PHP SDK v 3.2.3

Tags: php, facebook, heroku

Looks like after trying hard to create my first app on Facebook with SDK 4 [ [Facebook app fails to get Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24477042) ] with no success I need to go back to the older SDK v 3.2.3

But I want to know till which date the facebook app will work with the older PHP SDK v 3.2.3 ?
Do I need to tweak/install any other software on Heroku for the app ?

Comment: Well there is no change in the *creation of an app*. I dont understand why was it *no success*. Btw, v1.0 will be not function after April '15

Comment: @SahilMittal v 1 means ? I can only find v 3 and v 4 on the net. Does that mean that v 3 will be usable for at least a year ?

Comment: The new version that new SDKs are following is API v2.0, earlier one was 1.0. What you are talking is the PHP-SDK version.Yes you can use the v1.0 (SDK-3) but why to?- not recommended.